# problems using new GridLayout in Android

Tags: android, grid-layout

I am playing a bit with the new GridLayout introduced in Android > 4.0, and I am experiencing some strange results. Lets say I want to create just as a proof of concept a Dashboard made of a matrix of buttons and a editext view on top of them.

The Gridlayout contains 2 columns and 3 rows. 
The Edittext spans 2 columns in the first row.
There is 4 buttons in the remaining empty spots.

The problem I am having is that the edittext on the top is wider than it should be and my four buttons cannot be distributed evenly. Is there any way to accomplish this?

thanks!

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gridLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
android:columnCount="2"
android:columnOrderPreserved="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:rowCount="3"
android:rowOrderPreserved="true" >

<Space
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnSpan="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_columnSpan="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:text="Button" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_row="0" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial [Android User Interface Design: Creating a Numeric Keypad with GridLayout](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-creating-a-numeric-keypad-with-gridlayout/)

Tips: In the (Eclipse) ADT layout editor, press SHIFT when you resize gridlayout items to make them span columns and rows